# Searching in docs AppStoreConnect API

Tags: ios, api, app-store-connect

I want to use App Store Connect API for manage Ratings, Reviews, and Responses. I want to reply to comments and ratings. But I cannot find them in the documentation. She's pretty awkward. Help me please. Is there control over this or not?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not implemented in App Store Connect API gateway.

Instead of it you could use iTunes RSS for listing ratings and reviews. But you will not be able to manage them.

https://itunes.apple.com/COUNTRY/rss/customerreviews/id=APP-ID/sortBy=mostRecent/json

```
COUNTRY = us
APP-ID = 1145275343
```

https://itunes.apple.com/lt/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/sortBy=mostRecent/json